# Replace different Regex-Matches with Match-based results in Java

Tags: java, regex

One common usage for regex is the replacement of the matches with something that is based on the matches.

For example a commit-text with ticket numbers `ABC-1234: some text (ABC-1234)` has to be replaced with `<ABC-1234>: some text (<ABC-1234>)` (<> as example for some surroundings.)

This is very simple in Java

```
String message = "ABC-9913 - Bugfix: Some text. (ABC-9913)";
String finalMessage = message;
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("ABC-\\d+").matcher(message);
if (matcher.find()) {
  String ticket = matcher.group();
  finalMessage = finalMessage.replace(ticket, "<" + ticket + ">");
}
System.out.println(finalMessage);
```

results in`<ABC-9913> - Bugfix: Some text. (<ABC-9913>)`.

But if there are different matches in the input String, this is different. I tried a slightly different code replacing `if (matcher.find()) {` with `while (matcher.find()) {`. The result is messed up with doubled replacements (`<<ABC-9913>>`).

How can I replace all matching values in an elegant way?

Comment: Why don't you directly use `String.replaceAll()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use [`replaceAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29):

```
String input = "ABC-1234: some text (ABC-1234)";
System.out.println(input.replaceAll("ABC-\\d+", "<$0>"));
```

prints:

```
<ABC-1234>: some text (<ABC-1234>)
```

`$0` is a reference to the matched string.

[Java regex reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) (see "Groups and capturing").

Comment: Thanks. Much simpler than my solution. I just didn't know the $x syntax to reference the groups works with replaceAll...

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the replace() method transforms the string over and over again.

A better way is to replace one match at a time. The matcher class has an appendReplacement-method for this.

```
String message = "ABC-9913, ABC-9915 - Bugfix: Some text. (ABC-9913,ABC-9915)";
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("ABC-\\d+").matcher(message);
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
while (matcher.find()) {
  String ticket = matcher.group();
  matcher.appendReplacement(sb, "<" + ticket + ">");
}
matcher.appendTail(sb);
System.out.println(sb);
```

Comment: This will work, but you're doing more work than you need to.  This is roughly what `replaceAll()` does under the hood.